# Drift velocity current electricity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-current, velocity

I have a question which I got stumbled upon between two different options (MCQ), as it required to have only one correct option. So the question goes like this:

**In a metallic conductor, under the effect of applied electric field, the free electrons of the conductor :**
options are: (`Wherever potential is mentioned it is electric potential )

1. move in the straight line paths in the same direction.
2. drift from higher potential to lower potential.
3. move in the curved paths from lower potential to higher potential.
4. move with uniform velocity throughout from lower potential to higher potential.

I know that, generally electric field lines( by convention) starts from higher potential and goes towards lower potential which makes option 1 and 2 false. While option 3 is correct but I have doubt in option 4. wether option 4 is also correct.

option 4: according to me although there is an acceleration of free electrons inside the conductor due to electric field, the various forces like nuclear attraction, electron-electron repulsion, etc. makes it seems like the electrons are drifting with constant velocity from lower potential to higher potential.

Sir If have made any mistakes above please pardon me for my dull mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your *. . . . . drifting at constant velocity . . . . .* with *. . . . . drifting at constant **average** velocity . . . . .* thus negating option $4$.